# Until loop without using a while loop

Tags: python

I am making a game and all the game runs in a while loop. Because you can't use two while loop, how can I do an action **UNTIL** something.

Comment: use a `for` and a `break`

Comment: You _can_ use two wile loops, you know?

Comment: Can I use two while loop?

Comment: Please be more specific about what you really want to achieve. Learn how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Of course, why couldn't you? Are you asking how to break out of the outer loop from inside the inner loop?

Comment: if I use a break in a while loop that is in an other while loop, will it only break the second while loop?